# ios 9 universal link is not Working?

Tags: objective-c, ios9

I am facing some problem in **Universal link  iOS 9** 
So I followed the tutorial https://blog.branch.io/how-to-setup-universal-links-to-deep-link-on-apple-ios-9 and exactly use the same values as the one provided.

if app is already installed when i tap on **Universal link**,than i navigate to app store but is navigate to my App.

I have already done all the needed configuration given by Apple.
The Apple Association file is also ready in the link directory: WEB_PAGE:PORT_NUMBER/apple-app-site-association

Everything seems to be setup on this side.

I've added the entitlements, updated the provisioning profile, and everything's setup.

Has anyone perfected this? Is there something I missed out?

Comment: Ask Branch for help.

Comment: Try to longpress the URL, to see if the "Open XX App" appears.

Comment: when i longpress the URL but there have no option  "Open XX App"

Comment: Alex with Branch here: are you using the Branch service, or just trying to get Universal Links working on your own?

Comment: Hi Alex, i am not used Branch Service for the same.

Comment: somebody have any idea where i am wrong? Please Help me.